# In MVC, is it a good idea to let client JavaScript to handle the view component?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web

In a MVC web application, either PHP or ASP.net etc., is it a good idea to spit data to json/csv in a hidden div and let client side js to handle the presentation?

For example, if you want to present a table, instead of convert query results to HTML table at the server side (PHP or C# etc.), you can simply convert the query results to a json string and put it inside a div with display:none. And then, you use client side JavaScript to read the json data and present it as a HTML table or anything you want.

The benefit is that you can totally forget thinking about the presentation of the data while you are programming for the back end. You don't need to constantly revise the view code when you change the model / controller code, or vice visa.

One disadvantage is that there might be a risk for SEO.

Is there any other advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Please do not vote for close, God. If you really want to, please leave a constructive comment first. God. Please.

Comment: Uh oh. You're stirring up a hornets' nest here without knowing. This is actually a major discussion on the front(end). Should you render in the client or on the server? Or a mix of both? There's no commonly accepted catch-it-all solution, though. It mainly depends on your use case. Some apps will become better with a single-page-app dev style, but most should be rendered on the server for a plethora of reasons. (For the record, I did not vote to close.)

Comment: In my personal bubble, this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=render+on+server+or+in+client+javascript+spa) has some good discussions right on top. Client side rendering is often done in the context of a framework like React, Angular or VueJS.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know to use "render" as a keyword for googling this question.

Comment: Yes, that term comes actually as a bit of surprise when you use `print` or `echo` or similar usually. "Rendering" is more commonly used for graphics. For reasons somewhat opaque to me the discussion settled for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Disadvantages for table data**

-*It causes "Memory Leak" and much download size.*

Let's think you have 100.000 object in an array. It is just 50 MB. Every page load user download this data. It is not good for user.

-*It is static. It will be dynamic only if user refresh page.*

In dynamic websites data always changes. And user wants to follow it.

**What To Do**

As AngularJs, VueJs, ReactJs use scope to keep data in javascript. But that data must be simple (not like 100.000 length array).

If you are using table you can use page size and page count structure.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't spit the whole 50MB array to client.
2. User needs to refresh page even if I do server side rendering.